# Picture Frame widget resized

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab, picture-frame-widget

The size for the picture frame widget originally was 3x3. Now, inexplicably, it is only 2x2. How can I change it back or pick what size a widget should be?

I've created cue cards perfectly readable at 3x3 but at 2x2 too small to view the diagrams/text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Powering off and back on restored the 3x3 picture size... makes no sense, but it worked.